# create 3 List<column> after calling tojson()

Tags: c#, json, file

we created a new class that its constructor sets an email string and a List consisting of 3 objects, each column by default contain an empty `List<task>`.

We tried saving the board into a .json file by using the function `toJson()` but the `.json` file contains only the email string, we need the `.json` file to contain the email and the `List<column>` as well.

```cs
class Board : DalObject<Board>
{
    private readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
          System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private string email;
    private List<Column> columns;
    public Board() { }
    public Board(string email, List<Column> columns)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Columns = columns;
    }
    public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }
    internal List<Column> Columns { get => columns; set => columns = value; }


    public string ToJson()
    {
        var json = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true
        };
        log.Info("Board of user " + this.Email + " saved");
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, json);
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        base.controller.WriteBoard(this.Email, ToJson());
    }
}
```

---

```cs
class Column : DalObject<Column>
{
    private int columnOrdinal;
    private string columnName;
    private int limit;
    private List<Task> tasks;
    public Column() { }
    public Column(int columnOrdinal, string columnName, int limit, List<Task> tasks)
    {
        this.ColumnOrdinal = columnOrdinal;
        this.ColumnName = columnName;
        this.Limit = limit;
        this.Tasks = tasks;
    }

    public int ColumnOrdinal { get => columnOrdinal; set => columnOrdinal = value; }
    public string ColumnName { get => columnName; set => columnName = value; }
    public int Limit { get => limit; set => limit = value; }
    internal List<Task> Tasks { get => tasks; set => tasks = value; }
}
```

---

```cs
class Task : DalObject<Task>
{
    private int taskId;
    private string title;
    private string description;
    private DateTime creationDate;
    private DateTime dueDate;

    public Task() { }

    public Task(int taskId, string title, string description, DateTime dueDate, DateTime creationDate)
    {
        this.TaskId = taskId;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Description = description;
        this.CreationDate = creationDate;
        this.DueDate = dueDate;
    }
    public int TaskId { get => taskId; set => taskId = value; }
    public string Title { get => title; set => title = value; }
    public string Description { get => description; set => description = value; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get => creationDate; set => creationDate = value; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get => dueDate; set => dueDate = value; }
}
```

---

```cs
public void WriteBoard(string fileName, string content)
{
    File.WriteAllText(BaseBoard + fileName + ".json", content);
    log.Info("The new data saved");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON Serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) to serialize your classes (containing `List` or other data) into **JSON** and the save it to file:

```cs
var content= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(BaseBoard + fileName + ".json", content);
```

Comment: This is .NET Core. `JsonSerializer` can do this job as well.

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to downvote just because there is another option.

Comment: Downvoted because you provided a wrong suggestion. .NET Core doesn't have `JavaScriptSerializer` in its API. Sorry.

Comment: OP is explicitly using `System.Text.Json` in the provided code.

Comment: @aepot fair enough changed the answer. Now you can revisit your vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

`JsonSerializer` located in different Namespace and can't see the `internal` Property `Columns`. Make it public.

```csharp
public List<Column> Columns { get => columns; set => columns = value; }
```